# Webdriver Selenium different behavior on different computers

Tags: c#, windows, selenium, webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I wrote some code to do repetitive tasks with the Webdriver in C#.
My code works well on my PC but it is grabbing a different element on my boss's PC.

**The element I'm looking for:**

```
var InventMgmt = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ROOT/Inventory Management']/div/span"));
```

This element is from a WebApp my company is using and *it's the same across the network.*

The problem is that the Webdriver is clicking a **completely different element that is not listed in my code.**

Both PCs are using the same Corporate OS (Windows 10), with the same browser versions.

After reviewing my code and Inspecting Element in my boss's browser, I'm starting to believe the issue can only be coming from my boss's PC...what could cause this kind of issue?

Here's the innerHTML of the elements I'm looking for and the one that are actually being clicked:

**Trying to click the "Inventory Management" span:**

```
<div id="ROOT/Inventory Management" class="x-panel x-panel-noborder x-tree x-panel-collapsed" style="width: auto;">
    <div class="x-panel-header x-panel-header-noborder x-unselectable x-accordion-hd" id="ext-gen186" tabindex="0" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <span class="x-panel-header-text" id="ext-gen190">Inventory Management</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Element being clicked is the div with id "ROOT/Support Table"**:

```
<div id="ROOT/Support Table" class="x-panel x-panel-noborder x-tree" style="width: auto;">
    <div class="x-panel-header x-panel-header-noborder x-unselectable x-accordion-hd" id="ext-gen248" tabindex="0" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <span class="x-panel-header-text" id="ext-gen252">Support Table</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show `HTML` of that `span` element

Comment: @Andersson I added the code for both elements.

Comment: Is there any way of updating the page source to assign the id of the span element to something predictable? That way you could use By.Id and find the span element directly without using xpath.

Comment: I already did. Works on my PC not on my boss's PC again. Funny thing, if I click the ID using Javascript instead of the Webdriver it works. It really seems to be related to Zooming, Font-size, resolution or something like that...

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check your browser **'Zoom Level'. It should be 100%** for your automation to work as expected. I ran into a similar situation once.

I recommend restricting the driver from starting if zoom levels are not 100.

```
InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
ieOptions.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
ieOptions.IgnoreZoomLevel = false;
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IEDriverFolder, ieOptions);
```

Comment: It's actually one of the first thing I did. Sorry I didn't mention it...not working unfortunately.